# Saving files on mobile device with similar behavior of downloading

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, webrtc, cordova-plugins

I have a Blob in memory (received via WebRTC DataChannel) and I need to save it as a file on a mobile device (mainly on Android, but if possible also on iOS).

At present I use [cordova-file-plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) to allow the user to select a destination folder for saving.

I would like to **avoid folder selection** (which opens a modal with folder structure) and **when saving file do exactly like when starts a download from a server** (or an App store).

Therefore I'm looking for a plugin (or another solution) which may enable saving of a file in the same way as downloading from a site:

- save in the default download folder
- message in the notification area with some animation
- link to the file on notification click

I already tried [cordova-plugin-file-transfer](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) in conjunction with an HTML anchor and DataURL, but there are memory issues when saving relatively large files.

Comment: Did you figure out any solution for this? I am too facing this problem.